# (NaN, NaN) when getting latitude and longitude through GET

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I'm getting `(NaN, NaN)` when I trying to fetch the latitude and longitude information from an `GET` in JavaScript. Here's my code:

```
var GET = {};
var params = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
for (var i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var par = params[i].split('=');
    GET[par[0]] = par[1];
}

function initialize() {
    var latitude_longitude = new google.maps.LatLng(GET['coordinates']);

    // The basic code to call Google Maps JavaScript API v3 ...
}
```

Do I have to put the latitude and longitude in clear text (for example `... new google.maps.LatLng(59.328614,13.485847)`)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LatLng() takes two arguments, so you will need to split the coordinates:

```
function initialize() {
    var csplit = GET['coordinates'].split(',');

    var latitude_longitude = new google.maps.LatLng(csplit[0], csplit[1]);

    // The basic code to call Google Maps JavaScript API v3 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate, what's stored in `coordinates`?

You might have to use `split(',')`, then write `new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(value[0]),parseFloat(value[1]))`

Comment: `59.328614,13.485847` is in `coordinates`